# Meteor app on Heroku fails over time

Tags: heroku, meteor, mlab

I host my meteor app on Heroku with MongoLab add on (all free plans). Over time, the app will fail. I will not be able to login (using Account package), keep getting `Internal server error` as a response, no other helpful messages. To fix this I need to restart the dyno with `heroku ps:restart`.

But on the server side these errors are logged

```
2013-05-10 01:27:13.530748+00:00 app web.1 - - Exception in queued task: Error: failed to connect to [xxx.mongolab.com:41357] at Object.Future.wait (/app/.meteor/local/build/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:322:15) at _.extend._nextObject (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:485:47) at _.extend.forEach (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:506:22) at _.extend.getRawObjects (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:550:12) at _.extend._pollMongo (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:821:46) at Object._.extend._unthrottledEnsurePollIsScheduled [as task] (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:765:12) at _.extend._run (app/packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:126:18) at _.extend._scheduleRun (app/packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:104:14) EXCEPT
2013-05-10 01:27:13.530748+00:00 app web.1 - - - - - - - Heroku/auction-app
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/app/.meteor/local/build/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:564:74)
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at connection.on._self._poolState (/app/.meteor/local/build/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:124:15)
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at Socket.errorHandler (/app/.meteor/local/build/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:465:10)
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:329:14)
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/app/.meteor/local/build/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:564:74) Heroku/auction-app Context
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20) Heroku/auction-app Context
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at connection.on._self._poolState (/app/.meteor/local/build/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:124:15) Heroku/auction-app Context
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17) Heroku/auction-app Context
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at Socket.errorHandler (/app/.meteor/local/build/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:465:10) Heroku/auction-app Context
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17) Heroku/auction-app Context
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:329:14) Heroku/auction-app Context
2013-05-10 01:27:13.531106+00:00 app web.1 - - at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9) Heroku/auction-app
```

Seems like the error is due to failure to connect to the databse. But it doesn't explain why I have to restart the app, not the database (over at MongoLab).

Comment: Try to connect to ML from you pc. You may mistake in yor connection string or service is down.

Comment: The connection string is correct. It only stopped working after some time. The DB is never down and I can access it manually just fine. I need to restart heroku in order to get it to work again.

Comment: In this case only sevice support can help you.